# Memory leaks (Valgrind report)(C++)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

this is my simple code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>  
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class GeneralMatrix {
protected:
    int width;
    int height;

public:

    //Stores values of matrix size
    GeneralMatrix(int nr, int nc) {
        height = nr;
        width = nc;
    }
};

class RegularMatrix : public GeneralMatrix {
protected:
    vector<double>data;

public:
    //Constructor 
    RegularMatrix(int nr, int nc, const vector<double>& nums) : GeneralMatrix(nr, nc) {
        data = nums;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 double mm3[] = {10, 2, 3, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 2, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5};
 vector<double>k;

 for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
     k.push_back(mm3[i]);

 }
 GeneralMatrix *d = new RegularMatrix(4, 4, k);

 delete d;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I am trying to call constructor and give it vector of numbers to be stored in class internal vector. Everything works fine but Valgrind somehow finds memory leaks.

```
==4903==     in use at exit: 128 bytes in 1 blocks
==4903==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 6 frees, 396 bytes allocated
==4903== 
==4903== 128 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4903==    at 0x4029F34: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==4903==    by 0x8049679: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==4903==    by 0x8049347: std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_allocate(unsigned int) (in /home/ubuntu/Desktop/a.out)
==4903==    by 0x8048E50: double* std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_allocate_and_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double const*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >(unsigned int, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double const*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double const*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >) (stl_vector.h:1138)
==4903==    by 0x8048AD5: std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator=(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&) (vector.tcc:188)
==4903==    by 0x80489C0: RegularMatrix::RegularMatrix(int, int, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&) (mem2.cpp:37)
==4903==    by 0x80488AE: main (mem2.cpp:55)
==4903== 
==4903== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4903==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 1 blocks
==4903==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4903==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4903==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4903==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Edit: I posted wrong code without delete (now fixed), problem is in usage of vector.

Comment: You canned `new`. You did not call `delete`.

Comment: Tip of the day : don't put `new` in a can.

Comment: @Quentin unless you make sure to `delete` the can after!

Comment: Post edited delete is not working, just changed valgrind output.

Comment: @Quentin shouldn't you recycle cans?

Comment: @EdChum only in garbage-collected languages. But remember to use the yellow GC for metal and paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make GeneralMatrix's destructor **virtual**, otherwise you won't be able to properly delete derived objects through a base pointer.

Don't confuse pointers & references and dynamic allocation. You can very well use a pointer or a reference to a static or automatic object. "Polymorphism only works with pointers and references" isn't about the lifetime of the object, but the way of handling it. See that example : http://ideone.com/qmywMk

```
#include <iostream>
struct Base {
    virtual void sayHi() {
        std::cout << "Hi from Base!\n";
    }

    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual void sayHi() {
        std::cout << "Hi from Derived!\n";
    }
};

void sayHelloToMyValue(Base o) {
    o.sayHi();
}

void sayHelloToMyReference(Base &o) {
    o.sayHi();
}

void sayHelloToMyPointer(Base *o) {
    o->sayHi();
}

int main(int, char**) {
    Derived d;  // No dynamic allocation!
    Base &base = d;

    sayHelloToMyValue(base);
    sayHelloToMyReference(base);
    sayHelloToMyPointer(&base);

    return 0;
}
```

The first call passes `base` by value (copy), and thus loses its derived type. Both the others refer to the original Derived instance which can route the virtual function call.

Comment: Can you please help me with this little bit extended code [Link](http://pastebin.com/6xTd50sj) ? I dont want to start new question since it is similar to this one.

Comment: Syntax quirks and overuse of the `new` operator make me think you come from another language such as Java or C#. IMHO you should quickly read through a C++ course to grasp its idioms, in particular regarding memory management.

Comment: As for that new leak : RegularMatrix::createNew() returns a dynamically-allocated instance, that you never delete. Rules of thumb : Don't use dynamic allocation needlessly. Do think about who owns a dynamically-allocated object and ought to delete it. Use and apply _RAII_ (one of C++'s core principles).

Comment: I tryed to avoid using new, but I learned that polymorphism doesnt work with non-pointer types so i tryed to pass everything as reference or pointer that causes leaks.

Comment: @TomášPastorek see this same, now-edited answer for a quick briefing on C++ polymorphism.

Comment: Thank you, this explains a lot.